# Representing tree(menu) structure in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-database

I have this table.

```
id        parent
----------------
1         0 
2         0 
3         1 
4         3 
5         2
```

I want to export this into a column to a new table, which would look like this. It will represent the tree(menu) structure. So every single ID will have its own row but if it is connected to a parent four spaces would be added to make the hierarchy obvious.

```
     ID           etc...
-------------  ------------
|1          |
|    3      |
|         4 |
|2          |   
|    5      |
```

I could have only come up with a solution which is using set of cursors, so it depends on number of children. I tried to make a recursion but cant really think of a solution which would take data from one table, do recursion with spaces add and export it to a column in a new table. Thanks.

Comment: look for `cte` and this is more of formatting

Comment: Search recursive cte. This has been done thousands and thousands of times. But sometimes not knowing the term to search for is more than half of the battle.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, cast(id as varchar(max)) as hierarchy
      from t
      where parent = 0
      union all
      select t.id, cte.hierarchy + '-->' + cast(t.id as varchar(max))
      from cte join
           t
           on t.parent = cte.id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

This provides an even more explicit format for the hierarchy.  Although you can use indentation, I think the explicit hierarchy is much more informative.

Comment: Thanks. I just need to right now think about formatting it properly.

Answer (score 0):

is this helpfull

```
    declare @tmp table (id int, parent int)
    declare @NewTable table (id VARCHAR(50))

    insert into @tmp
    SELECT 1,0
    union
    SELECT 2,0
    union
    SELECT 3,1
    union
    SELECT 4,3
    union
    SELECT 5,2



    ;with name_tree as (
       select id,id as p1,parent
       from @tmp
       --where id = 4 -- this is the starting point you want in your recursion
       union all
       select p.id,c.id as p1, c.parent
       from @tmp c
         join name_tree p on p.parent = c.id  -- this is the recursion
    ) 



    INSERT INTO @NewTable(id)
    select REPLICATE( ' ' , (Count(*)-1)*4 )+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),id)
    from name_tree
    group by id

    select * from @NewTable
```